# Recoger valor numérico de un input

Tags: javascript, html, variables

me gustaría saber como recoger de un input de número un valor numérico. Es decir, algo que previo a "document.getElementById()" me devuelva no el texto sino el número. O sea, que lo convierta a número entero. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza parseInt()

este Convierte un argumento de tipo cadena y devuelve un entero de la base especificada.

```js
const miNumero = parseInt('1234', 10) //1234
// La base siempre debe ser 10 para numeros entero
```

Si el primer carácter no se puede convertir, devuelve NAN.

Solo se devuelve el primer entero encontrado.

Comment: Gracias maestro, excelente!